# Appending to a c++ array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to append the string variable `line` into a float array called `prices`. Here's what I have so far.

```
string newItem;
string filename = "rowPrices.dat";
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(filename);
if (inFile)
{
    cout << filename << " is loading. " << endl;
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        getline(inFile, line);
    }
}
```

How can I, without using vector append `line` into an array called `prices`? I would like to do:

```
line >> prices[i]
```

right after the:

```
getline(inFile, line);
```

but that obviously doesn't work. Quick note is that I plan on converting the string to a float value. How can I append?

Comment: You want to put a `string` into an array of `floats` ?

Comment: It will probably not get any easier than using a vector.

Comment: You're looking for `std::stof`. Note that `std::vector` and "complicated functions" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: `std::vector` wasn't made to complicate things, right the contrary. But if the assignment requires not using it, then you might want to take a look at `malloc()` and `realloc()`. Those functions allow you to dynamically allocate and resize arrays as needed.

Comment: If you can't use `std::vector` you have two options: Allocate an array that you are guaranteed you will never overfill or write your own simple version of `std::vector`.

Comment: `An EASY way of appending to a c++ array` there is none. `std::vector` is about it. You have the option of pointers, but I certainly wouldn't call it easy. Is there a reason you don't want to use an `std::vector`?

Comment: `realloc` and `std::string` are mortal enemies. If you try to use them together you have to expect sooner or later there will be a bloodbath. `string` is built around pointers, sometimes pointer to its own members. Reallocating the storage out from underneath the string has unpredictable results.

Comment: Since this question has been asked, I have learned more about vectors and understand the difference between the array and vectors, as well has how to use them. Could I please receive a couple upvotes to allow me to ask questions? Sorry if this question was not clear to all of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is 1 price per line in the file, you can put your `line` variable into a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and then use `operator>>` to read a `float` from it, eg:

```cpp
string filename = "rowPrices.dat";
float prices[15] = {};

ifstream inFile(filename);
if (inFile)
{
    cout << filename << " is loading. " << endl;
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        getline(inFile, line);
        istringstream(line) >> prices[i];
    }
}
```

Alternatively, in C++11 and later, you can use [`std::stof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) instead:

```cpp
string filename = "rowPrices.dat";
float prices[15] = {};

ifstream inFile(filename);
if (inFile)
{
    cout << filename << " is loading. " << endl;
    string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        getline(inFile, line);
        prices[i] = stof(line);
    }
}
```

Or, you could simply use `operator>>` on the `ifstream` itself:

```cpp
string filename = "rowPrices.dat";
float prices[15] = {};

ifstream inFile(filename);
if (inFile)
{
    cout << filename << " is loading. " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        inFile >> prices[i];
        // if there are other things on the line that you want to skip, uncomment this...
        // inFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: In a sense, though, it doesn't technically "append" to the array. Hopefully the OP will be okay with this solution though.

Comment: True, but since the loop counter was fixed at a small number, I figured a simple C array would suffice.  Obviously for larger arrays, something more dynamic will be needed.

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, this is not a bad solution by any means. I was just concerned it wasn't necessarily what the OP was looking for. But since the OP has weighed in now saying that it worked, I have now upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Just write them into the array as normal.

```
std::array<float, 15> prices;
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    getline(inFile, line);
    prices[i] = std::stof(line);
}
```